# How can i convert a dataframe datetime columns to Quanlib Date quickly

Tags: python, dataframe, apply, python-datetime, quantlib

Let's say one of the datetime column as below

```
PORT['ISSUE_DT']
```

0   2019-01-31
1   2018-10-24
2   2018-11-16
3   2018-11-16
4   2018-11-16

How can I convert it to Quanlib Date quickly?
I can convert one element as below, are there any methods without using 'for'?

```py
#DATA_DT
d = PORT['ISSUE_DT'][0]
#convert datetime to qt Date
d_qt =Date(d.day, d.month, d.year)
```

I know there is apply function like R, but I don't know how to deal with apply with the class attribute .

Answer (score 0):

QuantLib Python has 3 ways to construct the Date object:

- ql.Date(serialNumber), where the serial is the same as excel
- ql.Date(day, month, year)
- ql.Date(dateString, formatString)

If you want to convert the whole column you can use the apply method in pandas and use the construction method you prefer.

For example:

`PORT.ISSUE_DT = PORT.ISSUE_DT.astype(str).apply(lambda d: ql.Date(d, '%Y-%m-%d'))`

This will convert the column from strings to ql.Date

Comment: Thanks, @David Durate. It works.
I was trying some stupid non-working thing like below
```python
dd=lambda x:x.day
mm=lambda x:x.month
yy=lambda x:x.year


apply(Date, PORT['ISSUE_DT'].apply(dd),PORT['ISSUE_DT'].apply(mm),yy=lambda x:x.year)
```